# How to fix NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when using CrudRepository from Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Collegues, I'am trying to get data from DB using Spring Crud Repository:

```
@Component
public interface AssetsGapSortDAO  extends CrudRepository<AssetsGapSortEntity, Integer> {
   AssetsGapSortEntity getByIsin(String ISIN);
}
```

JPA entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Assets", schema = "dbo", catalog = "")
public class AssetsGapSortEntity {
    private BigInteger id;

    private String shortName;
    private String isin;
    private int registrationDate;
    /*Some other properties*/

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id")
    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ShortName")
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ISIN")
    public String getIsin() {
        return isin;
    }

    public void setIsin(String isin) {
        this.isin = isin;
    }

    /*Equals and hashcode methods*/


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ToStringStyle style = new NotNullToStringStyle();
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, style);
    }


}
```

When i run jUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OlmeSmbConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AssetsGapSortDAOTest {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtractionsDAOTest.class);

    @Autowired
    AssetsGapSortDAO assetsGapSortDAO;

    @Test
    public void getByIsin() throws Exception {
        log.info(assetsGapSortDAO.getByIsin("TT0W3888254").toString());
    }

}
```

i receive the naxt stackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
....
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assetInfoLoader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'assetsGapSortDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.comp.olme.jpa.dao.GapSort.AssetsGapSortDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    ....
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.comp.olme.jpa.dao.GapSort.AssetsGapSortDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 45 more
```

My config looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.comp.olme"})
@PropertySource("classpath:OlmeSmb-${env}.properties")
@EnableScheduling
public class OlmeSmbConfig {
/*There are DataSource, EntityManagerFactory beans etc....*/
}
```

When i use simple JPA everything works fine, but i would like to try CrudRepository.
So the question is why i receive `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and how to fix it?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

According to @javaguy advice i added to my config `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.comp.olme", entityManagerFactoryRef ="emGapSort", transactionManagerRef = "txManagerGapSort")
```

and the "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" was fixed, but the new one raise:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e4e8fdf': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createSharedEntityManager' parameter 0: 
Could not convert argument value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: 
Failed to convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44 implementing org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory';
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44 implementing org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 58 more
```

May be it is because i have more than one datasource in Spring Config (there are two for different DB)? How to fix it?
Sorry if it out of scope...

Comment: Why are you annotating `AssetsGapSortDAO` with `@Component`? I don't think it is necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spring-data` automatically provides the implementation for your DAO (repository) classes (i.e., for your `AssetsGapSortDAO` interface), but you need to tell where your repository classes can be found. So, add `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.yourproject")` class level annotation to your `OlmeSmbConfig` class to scan for the repositories.

I suggest you refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) for more understanding on how spring data works.

Also, I recommend you to annotate your `AssetsGapSortDAO` as `@Repository` rather than `@Component` (even though technically it works, marking `@Repository` makes more clear for repository/dao classes).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do add these annotations to the main application class, and that made the whole difference, it worked (even with multiple roots in the project)

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.yourproject")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.yourproject ... packageWithArgumentTypesToCrudRepository")
```